# What means SQL Azure is the abstraction of the logical database administration from the physical administration?

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database

I'm reading about SQL Azure and its differences from on-premises SQL. While I'm reading, I reached the following sentence: "A goal of SQL Azure is the abstraction of the logical database administration from the physical administration." and another one: "The abstraction of physical servers from logical servers will be a key factor in differentiating which features of SQL Server are supported by SQL Azure". Can somebody explain to me this sentences with an example?

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: With SQL Azure, you don't need to manage any servers, not even as VMs. You simply see a database that supports certain features and provides certain performance guarantees. Management of the actual physical servers or VMs is the responsibility of Microsoft.

Comment: OK, thank you, I understood. So Microsoft administers physical hardware and storage. For me as an administrator is the responsibility of manage only database objects and may be some security, right?

Comment: That is correct, you will need to manage the strength of your passwords, which users are assigned which passwords, firewall rules, auditing of changes, etc.  Microsoft is responsible for database back-ups, OS and SQL patching, performance, and high availability.